# How would I minimise this code, so it doesn't have to be repeated?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I am currently working on a shell script that will act as an autoinstaller for Multicraft.

I have written a snippet that checks to see if the OS is CentOS, and then decides what commands to use based off the version of CentOS in use.

```
# Check server is CentOS
if [ ! -f "/etc/redhat-release" ]; then
    echo -e ${COL_RED}"[FATAL]" ${COL_RESET}"This is not a standard CentOS Linux installation!
    Aborting..."
    quit
fi

# Check version of CentOS
OS_VERSION=$(rpm -qa \*-release | grep -Ei "oracle|redhat|centos" | cut -d"-" -f3)
```

An area where I use this functionality regularly is when starting / enabling services. For example:

```
if [ "${OS_VERSION}" = "7" ]; then
  systemctl enable mariadb
  systemctl start mariadb
elif [ "${OS_VERSION}" != "7" ]; then
  chkconfig mariadb on
  service mariadb start
else
  echo -e ${COL_RED}"[FATAL] "${COL_RESET}"Unable to derive OS version."
  echo "Aborting..."
  quit
fi
```

Every time I want to use this functionality, I currently have to repeat the same block, and I was wondering whether there might be any ways to abbreviate / minimise this, so as to make it look tidier?

Comment: Can you post an example of the repetition? I'm not sure which parts are repeated and which change.

Comment: Consider feature checks rather than version checks. `if command -v systemctl > /dev/null` will continue working in CentOS 8 and beyond, and will fail if systemd eventually goes away.

Comment: @JohnKugelman They are essentially the blocks within the statement. I.e. in this example, where systemctl, chkconfig, service and echo commands are used.

Comment: @JohnKugelman How would this be implemented? What the full if statement look like?

Comment: That's the full statement. `if command -v systemctl > /dev/null; then ...`

Comment: Great - thank you!